# Calculating integral with limits with different variables.

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

> Find $g'(\frac{1}{2}) $where $$\rm g(t) = \rm \int^{9\sin(\pi t)}_0e^{-s^2} ds$$

Can somebody help me how to do this? I don't know how to differentiate the $g(t)$ function since it's in 2 variables simultaneously. I would use implicint differentiation but $\frac{ds}{dt}$ is not defined.

Comment: This is a direct application of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: $$g'(t) = \frac{d}{dt} g(9\sin(\pi t))- \frac{d}{dt} g(0)=9\pi\cos(\pi t)g'(9\sin(\pi t))-0=9\pi\cos(\pi t)g'(9\sin(\pi t))$$
$$g'(\frac{1}{2}) =9\pi\cos(\frac{1}{2}\pi )g'(9\sin(\frac{1}{2}\pi))=9\pi g'(0)=9\pi $$ I was able to do this.

Comment: take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just
$$g'(t)=e^{-(9\sin(\pi t))^2}\cdot 9\pi\cos(\pi t)$$
by the Leibniz integral rule

Comment: But what happened to g(0)?

Comment: Fore sure $g(0)=0$

Comment: Okay thanks you